# Pass string variable to data Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a fuction to make my string array and pass this value to data inside highchart.

```js
(function ($, window, myapp) {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        console.log('the data array', myApp.dataArray);
        var conteudo = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myApp.dataArray.length; i++) {

            conteudo += "[\""
            conteudo += myApp.dataArray[i][0];
            conteudo += "\",";
            conteudo += myApp.dataArray[i][1];

            if (i == myApp.dataArray.length-1) {
                conteudo += "]";
            } else {
                conteudo += "],";
            }

        }


        console.log(conteudo);
        chart(conteudo);

    });
})(jQuery, window, myApp);
```

The result console.log is correct on variable conteudo
["2017-11-21",600000],["2017-11-22",-1200000],["2017-11-23",300000]

The problem is pass conteudo variable to hightchart:

```js
        series: [{
            name: 'Hours',
            colorByPoint: true,
           
                    data: [
                    
                   conteudo

                ]
            
        }]
```

Comment: I tried it, doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should pass array object to data field. No need to convert to string.

Also

> ["2017-11-21",600000],["2017-11-22",-1200000],["2017-11-23",300000]

This is not string array.

As I understand you are trying to do something like this:

```
data: [{
  name: '2017-11-21',
  y: 600000
}, {
  name: '2017-11-22',
  y: -1200000
}]
```

You can check an example 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-objects/

Comment: No, It´s diferent.I need pass exactly ["2017-11-21",600000],["2017-11-22",-1200000],["2017-11-23",300000] if I put manually my grafh works perfectly

Comment: @lorranpalmeira
What about this solution? 
http://jsfiddle.net/a0k3Lxbz/
Just use an array instead of a string

Comment: conteudo.push(myApp.dataArray[i][0]); conteudo.push(myApp.dataArray[i][1]); console.log: ["2017-11-24", 1080000, "2017-11-25", -180000, "2017-11-26", 300000] in grafh appear "2017-11-24", 1080000 correcty, but no show up the rest values.I think that close ].

Comment: You should follow the formats that **highcharts** specifies in the documentation: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series So in this case it could look like this:  `[["2017-11-24", 1080000], ["2017-11-25", -180000], ["2017-11-26", 300000]]`